# Insertar registros con checkbox C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Estoy dando de alta registros en C# ASP.NET con SQL Server, el problema es que no sé cómo declarar los checkbox para que cuando se seleccione uno o varios se den de alta en mi tabla.
Esto es lo que tengo:
La tabla sexo y edad son los checkbox.

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Initial   Catalog=Sistemaa;User ID=sa;Password=344");
 SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("insert into Empleados(nombre, trabajo, sexo, edad)values ("+this.txtnombre.text+",'"+this.txttrabajo.text+....(AQUI ES DÓNDE NO SÉ CÓMO AGREGAR LOS CHECKBOX))
```

Esta es mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para empezar me gustaría saber cómo has definido tu tabla `Empleados` en tu base de datos, de ser posible edita tu pregunta y muestranos tu tabla en la base de datos, y otro punto también muy importante es que no realices consultas dinámicas, se presta muchísimo a SQL Injection, una ventana de inseguridad bastante crítica.

Comment: Ya actualice mi pregunta

Comment: Excelente, puse un respuesta, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementado la respuesta de [Leandro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/45778/16841) pondría la siguiente validación:

```
string connstring = @"Data Source=(local);Initial   Catalog=Sistemaa;User ID=sa;Password=344";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring)) 
{

    string sql = @"insert into Empleados (nombre, trabajo, sexo, edad) values (@nombre, @trabajo, @sexo, @edad)"; 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtnombre.text); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trabajo", txttrabajo.text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo", checkboxSexoMasculino.checked ? "M" : "F");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edad", textEdad.text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

}
```

Esto significa que se evaluará `checkboxSexoMasculino.checked`, si el resultado es `true` se pondrá `"M"`, si el resultado es `false` se pondrá `"F"`, básicamente es un `IF` en una sola línea.

Comment: Una duda los parámetros se ponen aun que no tenga procedimientos almacenados?

Comment: Hola Marth, los parámetros se ponen siempre y cuando en la sentencia SQL así los declares con @nombre, por ejemplo. Se recomienda usar parámetros en lugar de consultas dinámicas (por cuestiones de seguridad y evitar SQL Injection), entonces, si en tu sentencia SQL pones un `INSERT` de 10 parámetros los debes declarar posteriormente en el `SqlCommand`. Esta es la documentación oficinal de Microsoft acerca del uso de parámetros y cómo evitar SQL Injection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: Gracias me quedó más claro

Comment: Excelente aporte, una pregunta, ¿Cómo se haría esto pero para guardar la selección de un RadioButton? Tomando en cuenta que son varios grupos de RadioButton.

Comment: Lo ideal sería que lances tus dudas en nueva pregunta, puedes basarte poniendo como referencia mi respuesta pero ahora para radiobutton

Answer (score 1):

Partamos de la base que no debes concatenar los valores en un string para asignar los parametros, sino que debes pasarlos usando Parameters del objeto command

```
string connstring = @"Data Source=(local);Initial   Catalog=Sistemaa;User ID=sa;Password=344";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
{

    string sql = @"insert into Empleados (nombre, trabajo, sexo, edad) values (@nombre, @trabajo, @sexo, @edad)"; 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtnombre.text); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trabajo", txttrabajo.text);
    //resto parametros

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

}
```

si los check son valores que necesitas insertar podrias definir campos del tipo 'bit' entonces asignas el parametros

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parambit", checkbox1.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo hice cómo me dijiste @--Leandro Tuttini 
Tengo otra duda, son varios check como habia mencionado, tengo que agregarlos todos en los parametros? puesto que en mi tabla solo tengo una columna para que ahi se en de alta los check seleccionados, no se si me explique

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Empleados(nombre,trabajo,sexo,edad,)values(@nombre,@trabajo,@sexo,@edad)", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", txtnombre.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWihValue("@trabajo", txttrabajo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexo",checkbox1....); //Aqui no me da la opción de checked
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@edad",checkbox2...);
```